# Is there a function in Orchard CMS that will retrieve the Theme directory?

Tags: orchardcms

I have images in my theme (in the Content/ directory) and I want to show them in different places.

My current approach is : `<img src="@Url.Content("~/Themes/MyTheme/Content/Images/image.gif")" />`

This works, but is not very maintainable <strike>(what if I want to switch themes, etc).</strike>

Is there an built in method, something like GetCurrentThemeDirectory() that would return the directory so I could do  or something like that?

Edit: from mdm's comment, I realize that changing the theme isn't a valid concern. I really just want to avoid typing out the url for every reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you referencing the image from? Module? Another theme?

If it is from the theme that has the image, then you don't need to worry about switching themes. If it is from another theme, then the image should be a part of the theme. If it is from a module, then it would make sense to store the image as part of the module or override it in the theme (see below).

If you wanted to have the image as part of the theme, then you could have the module return a 'default' shape and then override that in the theme. There really shouldn't be any reason to reference the theme's images from a module or vice versa.

**Edit after your edit**

In the themes I've written, I've followed what the Orchard authors do. Rather than using `<img>` tags, images are placed in `Styles/images`. They can then be referenced using the CSS `background-image` attribute.

In `Views/Branding.cshtml`:

```
<div id="header"></div>
<h1 id="branding"><a href="@homeUrl">@WorkContext.CurrentSite.SiteName</a></h1>
```

And then in `site.css`:

```
#header {
    /* snip */
    background-image: url(images/header.png);
    /* snip */
}
```

`Themes/TheAdmin/site.css` contains plenty more examples of this method.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question. I'm referencing from the same theme.

Comment: I suppose I could alternatively assign a custom setting so I could use @WorkContext.CurrentSite.ImageUrl. I searched '@workContext.CurrentSite' and found thishttp://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Adding-custom-settings.

Comment: But you would still have to type `WorkContext.CurrentSite.As<YourSettingsPart>().ImageUrl`. Use the CSS file, it's much easier ;)